# National Weather Service javascript jquery ajax 0 error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml

For some reason the National Weather Service's xml site does not work for me. When I say "does not work", I mean that I've tried both XMLHttpRequest and ajax to  GET the xml data from http://w1.weather.gov/xml/current_obs/KSFO.xml in order to write a script that displays current weather conditions. this is my code:

```
(function (){

updateWeather();
})();

function updateWeather(){

var url= "http://w1.weather.gov/xml/current_obs/KSFO.xml";

     $.ajax({
url: url,
dataType: 'xml',

error:function(xhr){
document.getElementById("weatherbox").innerHTML="error" +xhr.status+xhr.statusText;},
success:function(result,status,xhr){


 document.getElementById('weatherbox').innerHTML="success";

}
});

}
```

I know that you typically cannot request information cross domain, but the NWS site says its open to the public and im using an ajax call and since it seems as though nobody else has this problem it must not be a cross domain error, but i have tried using `crossDomain: true` in the ajax call. I have tried making the url "https:...." instead but that did nothing. I've tried specifying `type:'GET'` in the ajax call as well. Every time I run the script it returns `error0error` . Does anyone have any ideas? A working implementation of an ajax call would be even better, I've been working at this for days and it's driving me crazy that I can't seem to retrieve this data.

in response to the first comment, I looked into it before but it seems like the SOAP service is for requesting data packages, such as "the weather in SF from january to september" or something, and from the looks of this:

"XML Feeds of Current Weather Conditions
This page provides access to observed current weather conditions for about 1,800 locations across the United States and US Territories. Two file formats designed for computer to computer data transfer are provided. RSS and XML lists are provided to aid the automated dissemination of this information. More information on RSS and XML formats/feeds. Comments and feedback are welcome. There is additional information about this offering via this Product Description Document.

Select a State or Territory to locate XML weather observations feeds available:

Select a State/Territory above to list display list of observations stations An index list of all available stations is available in XML (900kb): XML Format"

and

"About XML
NWS offers hourly weather observations formatted with xml tags to aid in the parsing of the information by automated programs used to populate databases, display information on webpages or other similar applications. This format is not to be confused with RSS and cannot be read by RSS readers and aggregators. These files present more detailed information than the RSS feeds in strings friendly for parsing. Both the RSS and XML feeds offer URLs to icon images. Additionally, A list of what phrases may appear in the XML tag and suggested icons is available. To access these feeds, select a state and then the last XML link in the column."

from this site: http://w1.weather.gov/xml/current_obs/

i should be able to just use the xml from the link i posted above to retrieve current observation data and not packages like one would use for calculating or predicting forecast trends, AND it seems as though the SOAP request service actually would not work for my purposes because i cannot just order one data point.

Answer (score 0):

You could use JSONP request to avoid getting CORS errors, but this SOAP service does not wrap data in script. Just try reading the docs [here](http://api-portal.anypoint.mulesoft.com/noaa/api/noaa-national-weather-service-nws-api/docs/getting-started). You'll most probably have to create a client. NWS also provides a RESTful API. Read the tutorials [here](http://graphical.weather.gov/xml/rest.php).

Answer (score 0):

If you can use a php proxy, then look at http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/cross-domain-javascript-with-simple-php-proxy/ for the solution, and the corresponding code link at [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/vRvr20gz)

To summarize, the solution uses an intermediary to the remote site that sits at the same location as your JS code.  You invoke the proxy by setting the url parameter to your target. Let's say you saved the proxy code to filename 'weatherproxy.php' and your webserver supports the php module and curl support, then you would set your variable as

```
var url = 'weatherproxy.php?url=http://w1.weather.gov/xml/current_obs/KSFO.xml';
```

With no other options to your proxy, on success it will return a json with the form:

```
 { status: { http_code: 200 }, contents: "your xml contents as a string" }
```

From there you would have to invoke an xml interpreter on 'contents'.  Alternatively, there are parameters that you can supply to that proxy to return the raw xml. The parameter is '&mode=native'. I'm not sure though that jQuery can properly handle the XML that returns.

Have fun exploring the code.